# Where can I find the documentation for SyscallN, since syscall.Syscall6 has been deprecated as of Go 1.18?

Tags: windows, go, system-calls, golangci-lint

When I run [golangci-lint](https://golangci-lint.run/) on my Go code after changing the `go` value in my `go.mod` from `go 1.16` to `go 1.20`, I now get this linter warning:

```
windows.go:210:16: SA1019: syscall.Syscall6 has been deprecated since Go 1.18: Use SyscallN instead. (staticcheck)
        err, _, _ := syscall.Syscall6(fn, 5, addr, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&size)), 1, uintptr(family), uintptr(class), 0)
```

I wanted to compare the documentation for `SyscallN` to `syscall.Syscall6` to see if there were any gotchas for moving from the deprecated function to the recommended replacement, but I cannot retrieve documentation for the function with `go doc` or find documentation for the function in the [syscall package docs](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall). The syscall package docs have a `Syscall6` entry, but no `SycallN` entry. When I try to use `go doc`, I get this:

```
$ go doc syscall.SyscallN
doc: no symbol SyscallN in package syscall
exit status 1
```

Is `SyscallN` in a package other than `syscall`? Where can I find the documentation for `SyscallN`?

Note that this is for Windows-specific code guarded by a `//go:build windows` comment at the top of the `windows.go` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [@SteffenUllrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3081018/steffen-ullrich), I had to change the `Rendered for` dropdown value from `linux/amd64` like this:

[image]

to `windows/amd64` like this:

[image]

The documentation for `syscall.SyscallN` is available here (note the query component in the URL): https://pkg.go.dev/syscall?GOOS=windows#SyscallN